# \XeTeXglyph triggers previous character variant. How to avoid this?

Tags: fonts, xetex

I’m typesetting a document in Hoefler Text with XeTeX. I am however dissatisfied with the default position hyphens and dashes and much rather use other glyphs instead. I currently achieve this with the `\XeTeXglyph` macro.

Unfortunately, the last character before I call the `\XeTeXglyph` macro behaves as it was the last character of the line and is sometimes replaced by a variant glyph, which is often unsuitable.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 

\setromanfont{Hoefler Text}

% DOCUMENT
\begin{document}

\itshape % italics trigger variants much more readily

n-t % doesn't trigger n variant

n\XeTeXglyph 16 t % does trigger n variant

\end{document}
```

Is there another (better) way to invoke the right glyph without triggering the variant? Or is there a way to prevent triggering the character variant while using `\XeTeXglyph`, preferably without replacing the n by another `\XeTeXglyph`?

Comment: The way `\XeTeXglyph` is implemented makes it interrupt input stream, so the layout engine sees `n` alone, then `t` alone. There might be an AAT feature to access the form you want, check features reported by `aat-info.tex` and see if any helps.

Comment: I couldn’t find any way to access the hyphens or dashes I am looking for. But the `[ContextLineFinal=NoLineFinal]` you helped me discover allows me to avoid the n swash altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\fontspec` option `Contextuals=NoLineFinal` provides a way to avoid swashes at the end of the line. As this is (if I understood correctly) basically what happens at the layout engine level whenever I use `\XeTeXglyph` macro, I just had to ensure the option was set correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 

\setromanfont{Hoefler Text}
\newfontfamily \NoSwash [ItalicFeatures={Contextuals=NoLineFinal}]{Hoefler Text}
% Contextual=(No)LineFinal is meaningful only for the italic face of the family

% DOCUMENT
\begin{document}

\itshape

n-t

{\NoSwash n\XeTeXglyph 16 t} % disables it on the whole line

{\NoSwash n}\XeTeXglyph 16 t % disables it around the n only

{\fontspec[ItalicFeatures={Contextuals=NoLineFinal}]{Hoefler Text} n}\XeTeXglyph 16 t
% does the same locally

\end{document}
```

Not “breaking the input stream” would probably be better, but this works for now.

Comment: Very weirdly, TeXlive 2013 broke this workaround. I’m studying the case whenever I have time and will probably ask another question then.